# Setting message error with summary control in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have ErrorMessage in my attributes being set ..

For example:

```
          <asp:TextBox ID="FullName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="Surname_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
                runat="server" 
                Enabled="True" 
                TargetControlID="FullName"
                WatermarkText="Full Name" 
                WatermarkCssClass="watermark"  
                ></asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
              ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
               runat="server"
               ErrorMessage="Must insert full name"
               ControlToValidate="FullName"
               ForeColor="#FF3300"
               SetFocusOnError="True"
                ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                  <asp:CustomValidator 
                ID="CustomValidator2"
                runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="FullName"
                ClientValidationFunction="EmpIDClientValidate"
                OnServerValidate="EmpIDServerValidate"
                ErrorMessage="CustomValidator"
                Display="dynamic"
                ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Now I want the to insert the error message "Must insert full name" into the summary and leave the required control message having this only :"*". While the summary control should have the full message. Here is my summary control.

```
 <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="Summary"
              ShowMessageBox="true" 
              HeaderText="<b>Please review the following errors:</b>" ShowSummary="False"
            />
```

I know it can be done..But I dont know what attribute/property to add to make that happen?

**UPDATE:**

```
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
               runat="server"
               ErrorMessage="*"
               HeaderText="User name is empty"
               ControlToValidate="UserName"
               ForeColor="#FF3300" 
               Display="Dynamic"
               SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The control above produces *..which is what I want ..but the summary should take the ..."User name is empty" and display it..
Here is the summary again:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="Summary"
              ShowMessageBox="true" 
              HeaderText="<b>Please review the following errors:</b>" ShowSummary="False"
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what the answer should be:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
               runat="server"
               Text="*"
               ErrorMessage="Field cant be empty"
               HeaderText="User name is empty"
               ControlToValidate="UserName"
               ForeColor="#FF3300" 
               Display="Dynamic"
               SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

You should put text..that will represent the error in teh field..and the Error message will be represented in the validation summary control

Comment: Does this actually give you want you want? the only other solution i can think of is grabbing the errors off the Individual validators using jquery and applying them to the Validation summary

Comment: The problem is solved..no need to do any jQuery modifications